# Why is the FormData object not being sent via fetch()?

Tags: javascript, fetch, multipartform-data, fetch-api, form-data

```js
const userAPI = "https://reqres.in/api/users"

$("#myForm").on("submit", function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(this);

    // console.log(formData.get("inp_username"))

    fetch(userAPI, { 
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
    }).then((res) => { 
        return res.json();
    }).then(val=> console.log(val))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

<form class="form" id="myForm">
    <label for="inp_username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="inp_username" name="inp_username">
    <label for="inp_password">Password</label>
    <input type="text" id="inp_password" name="inp_password">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

For some reason it's not working. The `FormData` is not getting send. It seems that the data from the `form` is actually stored inside the object, as I can console it with `get()`, and the value is there, but it's not being send. The returned value should be the same username and password I send, but I'm not getting it back.

It works If I use `URLSearchParams`, but it doesn't work with `FormData` alone.

I tried changing the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and when I do that, I get a weird response which includes the sent data, but it also includes a whole bunch of gibberish I don't understand, and should not be there. I should be getting a simple JSON object with the data I sent.

It also doesn't work if I try to append the data instead.

Am I doing something wrong, or am I not understand something about the way `FormData` works?

**EDIT**

Just to make myself clear. The response from the server must be the same username and password you entered along with the ID and Credentials.

Try replacing the body with a query string instead of the FormData, and you will see the response you should get.

Example:

```
 headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
 body: "name=Donald"
```

The response will be:

```
{name: "Donald", id: "694", createdAt: "2021-06-27T12:41:47.798Z"}
```

Comment: everthing is working fine for me here.
Are you getting an error , an unwanted response status or what ?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. I'm just not getting the data I'm sending.

Comment: Can you post a snapshot? Are you really getting the username and password you entered?

Comment: Which Backend Are You Using ?

Comment: So your issue is not that Fetch can not send FormData - your issue is that your server-side code can not understand `multipart/form-data` and only understands `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: It's a free API. `"https://reqres.in/api/users"`

Answer (score 1):

You should transform the `formData` like the following:

```js
body: JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData))
```

And it will work.

Comment: It still doesn't work. You should be getting the same username and password you entered.

Comment: @happy_story the response isn't related to your question, the response comes from the server.